# Prove identity involving powers and trigonometric functions

Tags: complex-numbers

Need help proving that:
$$(1+\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha)^{n}= 2^{n}\cos^{n}\frac{\alpha}{2}\left(\cos\frac{n\alpha}{2}+i\sin\frac{n\alpha}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Hint: $\mathrm e^{\mathrm i\phi}=\cos\phi + \mathrm i\sin\phi$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:
$$
1 + \cos\alpha = 2\cos^2\frac{\alpha}{2} \\
\sin\alpha = 2\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha}{2}
$$

Comment: @Mykolas You're welcome!